# How can I optimize Objective-C singletons using ARC?

Tags: objective-c, performance, singleton, automatic-ref-counting

Using the standard pattern for a singleton in Objective-C, ARC still automatically generates retain and release calls around every use of the singleton, even though we know that the object will never be deallocated. In performance-sensitive code, these ARC-generated calls cause a significant amount of extra overhead. Is there any way to tell the compiler not to generate retain/release code for a singleton?

In my case, I'm writing a performance-sensitive parser of Japanese text. As part of my parsing, I often need access to an NSCharacterSet of kanji characters, which I have defined in a category on NSCharacterSet.

```
+ (id)kanjiCharacterSet
{
    static NSCharacterSet* kanjiCharacterSet = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once( &onceToken, ^
    {
        NSRange range = { .location = 0x4e00, .length = 0x9faf - 0x4e00 };
        kanjiCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithRange:range];
    } );

    return kanjiCharacterSet;
}
```

One of the most common places that I access this character set is to check for the existence of a kanji character in a string. This code lives in a category on NSString.

```
- (BOOL)containsKanji
{
    return [self rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet kanjiCharacterSet]].location != NSNotFound;
}
```

When I run this through a profiler, about 40% of the entire time spent in `[NSString containsKanji]` is in retain/release code. As for `[NSCharacterSet kanjiCharacterSet]`, excluding the first call where we actually generate the character set, about 80% of each call is spent in retain/release code.

If I set breakpoints in `objc_retain`, `obj_release`, and `objc_autorelease`, I can see that one retain and one autorelease are being added to the return statement from `[NSCharacterSet kanjiCharacterSet]`, one retain is being added in `[NSString containsKanji]` when it receives the value returned from `[NSCharacterSet kanjiCharacterSet]`, and one release is being added when we return from `[NSString containsKanji]`. It seems like all of these calls are unnecessary for a singleton. Is there any way to tell the compiler not to generate these calls?

I've found one workaround, which is to add a static variable to `[NSString containsKanji]` to store the character set in, but I'd love to find a more general solution.

Comment: Do you profile debug configuration or release? With optimizations turned on in release build those release/autorelease calls may be optimized by compiler. Also you can try to compile your file with arc disabled - may be that will reduce overhead

Comment: I'm profiling a release build. Thanks for the suggestion about disabling ARC. Unfortunately, it looks like if I disable ARC on the file that contains the singleton, the calling code will still have a release call generated as if the singleton was retained before it was returned, which forces me to write the retain into the singleton code anyway. =/

Comment: Also, + (id)kanjiCharacterSet; should be + (instancetype)kanjiCharacterSet;

Comment: I almost made it return instancetype, but I noticed that the character set singletons Apple includes in NSCharacterSet return id, so I figured I'd follow their convention. I guess I figured there must be a reason they didn't convert them to instancetype.

Comment: Have you looked at using `CFString` and `CFCharacterSet` from Core Foundation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method which calls kanjiCharacterSet repeatedly, cache a copy. Obviously that kind of thing should only be done when it is performance critical.

```
- (BOOL)containsKanji
{
    static NSCharacterSet* cachedKanji = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once (&onceToken, ^{
        cachedKanji = [NSCharacterSet kanjiCharacterSet];
    });

    return [self rangeOfCharacterFromSet: cachedKanji].location != NSNotFound;
}
```

Comment: so you are dispatching once a method that dispatches once object creation. I doubt there is much performance to gain here.

Comment: This is actually what I'm doing now. It's a significant performance improvement because there are no ARC-generated `retain` or `release` calls when you access `cachedKanji`.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: You missed the cleverness of the code. The cached instance will never again be retained or released.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t say what percentage of the total time is in -containsKanji, which is the only relevant metric for whether you should optimise that routine. If it’s, like, 1% of your total time, then it doesn’t matter if it spends all its time retaining or spinning or doing the dishes.

If it *is* in fact your big time sync, you should stop using objects in that method, a bit...it’s the big advantage of Objective-C, that we get to write low-level code in the middle of our high-level code.

In your case, since Kanji is from 0x4e00 to 0x9faf, I’d just write something like:

```
- (BOOL)containsKanji;
{
    const NSUInteger bufferSize = 256;
    unichar buffer[bufferSize];

    for (NSUInteger characterIndex = 0; characterIndex < self.length; characterIndex += bufferSize) {
        const NSUInteger charactersToFetch = MIN(bufferSize, self.length - characterIndex);
        [self getCharacters:buffer range:(NSRange){characterIndex, charactersToFetch}];

        for (NSUInteger checkCharacterIndex = 0; checkCharacterIndex < charactersToFetch; checkCharacterIndex++) {
            unichar characterToCheck = buffer[characterIndex + checkCharacterIndex];
            if (characterToCheck >= 0x4e00 && characterToCheck <= 0x9faf)
                return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Note I haven’t compiled this code, so you might need to fix typos and such.

Comment: It's about 7% of my total time, so it seemed worth taking a stab at improving. I'm somewhat reluctant to go down this path if I don't have to, just because of the reliability guaranteed in using methods like `rangeOfCharacterFromSet` instead of rolling my own. But I suppose that's the tradeoff, isn't it?

Comment: As far as efficiency hacks go, going from 9 to 11 lines of code isn’t bad. And, honestly, I’ve mostly given up on spreading code around in categories like that, unless it’s used many places—it makes it hard to find the actual code when there’s a bug. If this method is only called in one place, put the code inline. Don’t generalise too soon.

Comment: Thanks Wil. I agree with everything you're saying, and this might be the direction I end up going down. I suppose I've just been bitten by character encoding oddities enough times to be wary of rolling my own code for this kind of thing. Plus, I'm still curious if there's a more general solution for improving the performance of accessing a singleton in a tight inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

I found a partial solution by adding `__attribute__((ns_returns_retained))` to the method declaration:

```
+ (id)kanjiCharacterSet __attribute__((ns_returns_retained));
```

According to the [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#retained-return-values), this forces the compiler to treat the method the same way it would treat a method that starts with `alloc`, `copy`, `init`, `mutableCopy`, or `new`. Instead of four retain/release related calls, it only generates two: a single retain in `[NSCharacterSet kanjiCharacterSet]` and a single release in the calling code.

Comment: Looks like `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED` can be used in place of the less-pretty `__attribute__((ns_returns_retained)`. However, the notes for the `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED` declaration warn against using either technique when the method conforms to Cocoa naming rules (although you may rightly consider performance of a critical method to be one of the "exceptional circumstances" for which this option was created).